# Query Hierarchy

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a Hierarchy problem. I have a four level Hierarchy and i need to take the user from the low level to see all the upper levels.I can take the hierarchy from the low level to the upper as you can see:

```
select * from test1 


    **username**        **NAME**            **VALUE**
 1  e.gkioka            TEAM LEADER     x.xrysanthakopo
 2  e.gkioka            COACH           e.gkioka
 3  e.xathigianni       AGENT           e.xathigianni
 4  e.xathigianni       COACH           e.gkioka
 5  t.argentis          SUPERVISOR      t.argentis
 6  x.xrysanthakopo     SUPERVISOR      t.argentis
 6  x.xrysanthakopo     TEAM LEADER     x.xrysanthakopo
```

here is the username and the roles(AGENT is the low and goes COACH,TEAM_LEADER,SUPERVISOR(upper level))

this is the query for getting the hierarchy for low to the upper

```
 select t1.username as AGENT,t1.value as COACH ,t2.VALUE as TEAM_LEADER,t3.VALUE as SUPERVISOR
 from test1 t1,test1 t2, test1 t3
 where t1.username='e.xathigianni'
 and (t2.USERNAME=t1.VALUE and t1.name='COACH' and t2.name='TEAM LEADER') 
 and t3.USERNAME=t2.VALUE and t2.name='TEAM LEADER' and t3.name='SUPERVISOR'
```

that gives me the right hierarchy

```
        AGENT           COACH           TEAM_LEADER         SUPERVISOR
 - 1  e.xathigianni     e.gkioka        x.xrysanthakopo     t.argentis
```

My problem is when i put second level(e.gkioka(COACH)) or third level(x.xrysanthakopo TEAM_LEADER)
it doesent give me the right data.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please review this duplicate link and then revert back here if you still have a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-data+recursive-query+sql)

Comment: i cant understand the other thread the hierarchy is ok its the query for the other levels that doesent work thats why i asked you.